# App Hangs on Splash Screen [Android only] abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed"

Tags: telerik, nativescript

When i run my NativeScript application on an Android Emulator or device, the app hangs on the splash screen and never initializes. The apps name is "projectamobileapp"

Error Log:

```
C:\Users\akalkandelen>adb logcat
--------- beginning of main
05-03 14:40:53.434  1813  2032 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@8f80ee4)
05-03 14:40:53.435  1813  1832 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@8f80ee4)
05-03 14:40:59.927  1825  1828 D hwcomposer: hw_composer sent 6 syncs in 60s
--------- beginning of system
05-03 14:40:59.985  1813  2159 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity bnds=[641,342][843,600]} from uid 10040
05-03 14:41:00.018  1562 21006 W audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 18375986 , only wrote 18375840
05-03 14:41:00.106 25009 25138 W GCoreFlp: No location to return for getLastLocation()
05-03 14:41:00.139  1813  1836 W ActivityManager: Slow operation: 74ms so far, now at startProcess: returned from zygote!
05-03 14:41:00.143  1813  1836 W ActivityManager: Slow operation: 78ms so far, now at startProcess: done updating battery stats
05-03 14:41:00.143  1813  1836 W ActivityManager: Slow operation: 78ms so far, now at startProcess: building log message
05-03 14:41:00.143  1813  1836 I ActivityManager: Start proc 25502:com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/u0a112 for activity com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
05-03 14:41:00.143  1813  1836 W ActivityManager: Slow operation: 78ms so far, now at startProcess: starting to update pids map
05-03 14:41:00.143  1813  1836 W ActivityManager: Slow operation: 78ms so far, now at startProcess: done updating pids map
05-03 14:41:00.209 24449 24532 I MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
05-03 14:41:00.210 24449 24614 I DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled
05-03 14:41:00.221 24449 24556 I AudioController: internalShutdown
05-03 14:41:00.222 25502 25502 I ojectamobileap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-03 14:41:00.223 24449 24557 I MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
05-03 14:41:00.280  1572  1630 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8298496
05-03 14:41:00.292  1562 21006 W audio_hw_generic: Hardware backing HAL too slow, could only write 0 of 720 frames
05-03 14:41:00.300  1670  1849 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xef7518c0, tid 1849
05-03 14:41:00.317 24449 24556 I MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close  SR : 16000 CC : 16 SO : 1999
05-03 14:41:00.357 25502 25502 W ojectamobileap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-03 14:41:00.387 24449 24566 I MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
05-03 14:41:00.418 25502 25509 E ojectamobileap: Failed to send DDMS packet REAQ to debugger (-1 of 20): Broken pipe
05-03 14:41:00.464  2416  2426 I s.nexuslaunche: Background concurrent copying GC freed 103621(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 20(1908KB) LOS objects, 25% free, 17MB/23MB, paused 518us total 140.249ms
05-03 14:41:00.475  2416  2423 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe22a0440, tid 2423
05-03 14:41:00.475  2416  2423 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:00.489  2416  2423 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe22a0440, tid 2423
05-03 14:41:00.490  2416  2423 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:00.490  1813  1822 I system_server: NativeAlloc concurrent copying GC freed 61391(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 5(100KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 11MB/17MB, paused 733us total 279.301ms
05-03 14:41:00.681  2416  2426 I s.nexuslaunche: Background concurrent copying GC freed 3072(315KB) AllocSpace objects, 40(11MB) LOS objects, 22% free, 20MB/26MB, paused 2.856ms total 138.492ms
05-03 14:41:00.828 25502 25502 I TNS.Native: NativeScript Runtime Version 5.1.0, commit 4497f43b69cb57ce65ece2aac5b98b2010f85857
05-03 14:41:00.828 25502 25502 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad
05-03 14:41:00.828 25502 25502 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad END
05-03 14:41:00.936 25502 25502 W ojectamobileap: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Boolean;->value:Z (light greylist, JNI)
05-03 14:41:00.985  1670  1849 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to set client state on removed layer: Surface(name=AppWindowToken{f993550 token=Token{eaa1f13 ActivityRecord{ed75a02 u0 com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity t219}}})/@0x8652cfe - animation-leash#0
05-03 14:41:00.985  1670  1849 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to set client state on removed layer: Surface(name=AppWindowToken{d3df77c token=Token{8b51e6f ActivityRecord{f138d4e u0 com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity t2}}})/@0x9cf4da8 - animation-leash#0
05-03 14:41:00.985  1670  1849 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to destroy on removed layer: Surface(name=AppWindowToken{f993550 token=Token{eaa1f13 ActivityRecord{ed75a02 u0 com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity t219}}})/@0x8652cfe - animation-leash#0
05-03 14:41:00.985  1670  1849 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to destroy on removed layer: Surface(name=AppWindowToken{d3df77c token=Token{8b51e6f ActivityRecord{f138d4e u0 com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher/.NexusLauncherActivity t2}}})/@0x9cf4da8 - animation-leash#0
05-03 14:41:00.990  1825  1825 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:00.991  1825  1825 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe71c01c0, tid 1825
05-03 14:41:00.992  1825  1825 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:00.994  1825  1825 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe71c01c0, tid 1825
05-03 14:41:00.994 24449 24502 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe15178e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe2726410)
05-03 14:41:00.995  1825  1825 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:00.997  1825  1825 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe71c01c0, tid 1825
05-03 14:41:00.998  1825  1825 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:01.000  1825  1825 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe71c01c0, tid 1825
05-03 14:41:01.000  1825  1825 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:01.004  1825  1825 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe71c01c0, tid 1825
05-03 14:41:01.004  1670  1714 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:01.005  1825  1825 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:01.008  1825  1825 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe71c01c0, tid 1825
05-03 14:41:01.006  1670  1714 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xef73f640, tid 1714
05-03 14:41:01.009  1670  1714 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:01.009  1825  1825 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:01.012  1825  1825 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe71c01c0, tid 1825
05-03 14:41:01.012  1825  1825 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:01.015  1965  2211 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcd5fd420: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xcd6b82b0)
05-03 14:41:01.017  1670  1714 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xef751980, tid 1714
05-03 14:41:01.018  1670  1714 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:01.022  1670  1714 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xef751980, tid 1714
05-03 14:41:01.026  1670  1714 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:01.029  2416  2545 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe3f058a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe3f03520)
05-03 14:41:01.030  1965  2211 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcd5fd420: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xcd6b82b0)
05-03 14:41:01.037  1825  1825 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe71c01c0, tid 1825
05-03 14:41:01.041  1965  2211 D EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcd5fd420: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xcd6b82b0)
05-03 14:41:01.061  1670  1714 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf2e18400, tid 1714
05-03 14:41:01.062  1670  1714 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:01.067  1670  1714 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xf2e18400, tid 1714
05-03 14:41:01.069  1670  1714 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:01.076  1670  1714 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xef751980, tid 1714
05-03 14:41:01.077  1670  1714 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:01.080  1670  1714 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xef751980, tid 1714
05-03 14:41:01.081  1670  1714 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_unregister_buffer: exiting HostConnection (is buffer-handling thread)
05-03 14:41:01.148 25502 25502 D TNS.Native: V8 version 6.9.427.23
--------- beginning of crash
05-03 14:24:08.171 22576 22576 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:01.200 25502 25502 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:01.234  1813  4271 I ActivityManager: Process com.transperfect.projectamobileapp (pid 25502) has died: fore TOP
05-03 14:41:01.234  1671  1671 I Zygote  : Process 25502 exited due to signal (6)
05-03 14:41:01.234  1813  1837 W libprocessgroup: kill(-25502, 9) failed: No such process
05-03 14:41:01.234  1813  1837 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10112 pid 25502 in 0ms
05-03 14:41:01.258  1813  1836 I ActivityManager: Start proc 25522:com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/u0a112 for activity com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
05-03 14:41:01.256 25522 25522 I ojectamobileap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-03 14:41:01.288 25522 25522 W ojectamobileap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-03 14:41:01.572 25522 25522 I TNS.Native: NativeScript Runtime Version 5.1.0, commit 4497f43b69cb57ce65ece2aac5b98b2010f85857
05-03 14:41:01.573 25522 25522 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad
05-03 14:41:01.573 25522 25522 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad END
05-03 14:41:01.649 25522 25522 W ojectamobileap: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Boolean;->value:Z (light greylist, JNI)
05-03 14:41:01.661 25522 25522 D TNS.Native: V8 version 6.9.427.23
05-03 14:41:01.201 25502 25502 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:01.666 25522 25522 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:01.705  1813 16298 I ActivityManager: Process com.transperfect.projectamobileapp (pid 25522) has died: fore TOP
05-03 14:41:01.705  1813  1837 W libprocessgroup: kill(-25522, 9) failed: No such process
05-03 14:41:01.711  1671  1671 I Zygote  : Process 25522 exited due to signal (6)
05-03 14:41:01.733  1813  1836 I ActivityManager: Start proc 25542:com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/u0a112 for activity com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
05-03 14:41:01.737 25542 25542 I ojectamobileap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-03 14:41:01.745  1813  1837 W libprocessgroup: kill(-25522, 9) failed: No such process
05-03 14:41:01.745  1813  1837 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10112 pid 25522 in 39ms
05-03 14:41:01.771 25542 25542 W ojectamobileap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-03 14:41:02.028 25542 25542 I TNS.Native: NativeScript Runtime Version 5.1.0, commit 4497f43b69cb57ce65ece2aac5b98b2010f85857
05-03 14:41:02.028 25542 25542 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad
05-03 14:41:02.028 25542 25542 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad END
05-03 14:41:02.094 25542 25542 W ojectamobileap: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Boolean;->value:Z (light greylist, JNI)
05-03 14:41:02.102 25542 25542 D TNS.Native: V8 version 6.9.427.23
05-03 14:41:01.667 25522 25522 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:02.112 25542 25542 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:02.154  1813  3407 I ActivityManager: Process com.transperfect.projectamobileapp (pid 25542) has died: fore TOP
05-03 14:41:02.154  1671  1671 I Zygote  : Process 25542 exited due to signal (6)
05-03 14:41:02.154  1813  1837 W libprocessgroup: kill(-25542, 9) failed: No such process
05-03 14:41:02.154  1813  1837 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10112 pid 25542 in 0ms
05-03 14:41:02.175  1813  1836 I ActivityManager: Start proc 25562:com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/u0a112 for activity com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
05-03 14:41:02.181 25562 25562 I ojectamobileap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-03 14:41:02.215 25562 25562 W ojectamobileap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-03 14:41:02.257 25562 25569 E ojectamobileap: Failed to send DDMS packet REAQ to debugger (-1 of 20): Broken pipe
05-03 14:41:02.493 25562 25562 I TNS.Native: NativeScript Runtime Version 5.1.0, commit 4497f43b69cb57ce65ece2aac5b98b2010f85857
05-03 14:41:02.493 25562 25562 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad
05-03 14:41:02.493 25562 25562 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad END
05-03 14:41:02.562 25562 25562 W ojectamobileap: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Boolean;->value:Z (light greylist, JNI)
05-03 14:41:02.568 25562 25562 D TNS.Native: V8 version 6.9.427.23
05-03 14:41:02.113 25542 25542 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:02.571 25562 25562 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:02.604  1813  3407 I ActivityManager: Process com.transperfect.projectamobileapp (pid 25562) has died: fore TOP
05-03 14:41:02.605  1813  1837 W libprocessgroup: kill(-25562, 9) failed: No such process
05-03 14:41:02.605  1813  1837 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10112 pid 25562 in 0ms
05-03 14:41:02.605  1671  1671 I Zygote  : Process 25562 exited due to signal (6)
05-03 14:41:02.622 25581 25581 I ojectamobileap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-03 14:41:02.625  1813  1836 I ActivityManager: Start proc 25581:com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/u0a112 for activity com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
05-03 14:41:02.643 25581 25581 W ojectamobileap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-03 14:41:02.822 25581 25581 I TNS.Native: NativeScript Runtime Version 5.1.0, commit 4497f43b69cb57ce65ece2aac5b98b2010f85857
05-03 14:41:02.822 25581 25581 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad
05-03 14:41:02.822 25581 25581 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad END
05-03 14:41:02.865 25581 25581 W ojectamobileap: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Boolean;->value:Z (light greylist, JNI)
05-03 14:41:02.872 25581 25581 D TNS.Native: V8 version 6.9.427.23
05-03 14:41:02.572 25562 25562 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:02.877 25581 25581 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:02.914  1813  4271 I ActivityManager: Process com.transperfect.projectamobileapp (pid 25581) has died: fore TOP
05-03 14:41:02.914  1813  1837 W libprocessgroup: kill(-25581, 9) failed: No such process
05-03 14:41:02.914  1671  1671 I Zygote  : Process 25581 exited due to signal (6)
05-03 14:41:02.928 25600 25600 I ojectamobileap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-03 14:41:02.935  1813  1836 I ActivityManager: Start proc 25600:com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/u0a112 for activity com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
05-03 14:41:02.949 25600 25600 W ojectamobileap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-03 14:41:02.954  1813  1837 W libprocessgroup: kill(-25581, 9) failed: No such process
05-03 14:41:02.954  1813  1837 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10112 pid 25581 in 39ms
05-03 14:41:03.074 25009 25138 W GCoreFlp: No location to return for getLastLocation()
05-03 14:41:03.135 25600 25600 I TNS.Native: NativeScript Runtime Version 5.1.0, commit 4497f43b69cb57ce65ece2aac5b98b2010f85857
05-03 14:41:03.135 25600 25600 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad
05-03 14:41:03.135 25600 25600 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad END
05-03 14:41:03.182 25600 25600 W ojectamobileap: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Boolean;->value:Z (light greylist, JNI)
05-03 14:41:03.188 25600 25600 D TNS.Native: V8 version 6.9.427.23
05-03 14:41:02.878 25581 25581 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:03.191 25600 25600 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:03.214  1562  1562 W audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 18680642 , only wrote 18529200
05-03 14:41:03.234  1671  1671 I Zygote  : Process 25600 exited due to signal (6)
05-03 14:41:03.234  1813  3407 I ActivityManager: Process com.transperfect.projectamobileapp (pid 25600) has died: fore TOP
05-03 14:41:03.235  1813  1837 W libprocessgroup: kill(-25600, 9) failed: No such process
05-03 14:41:03.235  1813  1837 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10112 pid 25600 in 0ms
05-03 14:41:03.246 25619 25619 I ojectamobileap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-03 14:41:03.251  1813  1836 I ActivityManager: Start proc 25619:com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/u0a112 for activity com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
05-03 14:41:03.265 25619 25619 W ojectamobileap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-03 14:41:03.435  1813  2032 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock acquired by sendMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@b9d7f75)
05-03 14:41:03.435  1813  1832 I GnssLocationProvider: WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@b9d7f75)
05-03 14:41:03.444 25619 25619 I TNS.Native: NativeScript Runtime Version 5.1.0, commit 4497f43b69cb57ce65ece2aac5b98b2010f85857
05-03 14:41:03.444 25619 25619 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad
05-03 14:41:03.444 25619 25619 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad END
05-03 14:41:03.487 25619 25619 W ojectamobileap: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Boolean;->value:Z (light greylist, JNI)
05-03 14:41:03.494 25619 25619 D TNS.Native: V8 version 6.9.427.23
05-03 14:41:03.191 25600 25600 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:03.498 25619 25619 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:03.534  1813 16298 I ActivityManager: Process com.transperfect.projectamobileapp (pid 25619) has died: fore TOP
05-03 14:41:03.534  1671  1671 I Zygote  : Process 25619 exited due to signal (6)
05-03 14:41:03.535  1813  1837 W libprocessgroup: kill(-25619, 9) failed: No such process
05-03 14:41:03.535  1813  1837 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10112 pid 25619 in 0ms
05-03 14:41:03.546 25638 25638 I ojectamobileap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-03 14:41:03.552  1813  1836 I ActivityManager: Start proc 25638:com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/u0a112 for activity com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
05-03 14:41:03.563 25638 25638 W ojectamobileap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-03 14:41:03.736 25638 25638 I TNS.Native: NativeScript Runtime Version 5.1.0, commit 4497f43b69cb57ce65ece2aac5b98b2010f85857
05-03 14:41:03.736 25638 25638 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad
05-03 14:41:03.737 25638 25638 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad END
05-03 14:41:03.778 25638 25638 W ojectamobileap: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Boolean;->value:Z (light greylist, JNI)
05-03 14:41:03.785 25638 25638 D TNS.Native: V8 version 6.9.427.23
05-03 14:41:03.498 25619 25619 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:03.789 25638 25638 F libc    : /usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-release-r17/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:73: abort_message: assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type tns::NativeScriptException" failed
05-03 14:41:03.845  1671  1671 I Zygote  : Process 25638 exited due to signal (6)
05-03 14:41:03.845  1813  2095 I ActivityManager: Process com.transperfect.projectamobileapp (pid 25638) has died: fore TOP
05-03 14:41:03.845  1813  1837 W libprocessgroup: kill(-25638, 9) failed: No such process
05-03 14:41:03.845  1813  1837 I libprocessgroup: Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10112 pid 25638 in 0ms
05-03 14:41:03.857 25658 25658 I ojectamobileap: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-03 14:41:03.861  1813  1836 I ActivityManager: Start proc 25658:com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/u0a112 for activity com.transperfect.projectamobileapp/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity
05-03 14:41:03.873 25658 25658 W ojectamobileap: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-03 14:41:04.046 25658 25658 I TNS.Native: NativeScript Runtime Version 5.1.0, commit 4497f43b69cb57ce65ece2aac5b98b2010f85857
05-03 14:41:04.046 25658 25658 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad
05-03 14:41:04.046 25658 25658 D TNS.Native: JNI_ONLoad END
05-03 14:41:04.088 25658 25658 W ojectamobileap: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Boolean;->value:Z (light greylist, JNI)
05-03 14:41:04.094 25658 25658 D TNS.Native: V8 version 6.9.427.23
```

Ive tried deleting platform hooks and reinstalling everything, even did a clean install of nativescript and tns, nothing helped.

The app hanging happens on ANDROID ONLY, both on Emulators and real devices of different Android versions and API levels.

My package.json

```
    "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.transperfect.projectamobileapp",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "5.1.0"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "5.1.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
    "nativescript-angular": "~7.0.0",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.3.0",
    "nativescript-pdf-view": "2.0.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-calendar": "3.9.1",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "5.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "~5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "~7.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "4.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-sass": "^1.6.0",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.7.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~0.18.0",
    "tns-platform-declarations": "^5.0.5",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
```

Please let me know if you need any further information or logs.

Comment: Whats your tns runtime / tns core modules / Android OS version on your device? Does it happen even on a hello world application or is this something specific to the project?

Comment: @Manoj I edited the question with my package.json. This is a project im working on and not just a hello world app. The app hangs on any android emulator but the error log above i got from emulator with API 28 Android 9.0

Comment: Can you share a sample project where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: @Manoj sorry i am not able to provide a project where the issue can be reproduced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using a filesystem and rendering a pdf unto a file using fs.knownfolders.documents(). Turns out the error happens because i do documents.clear() at ngondestroy. I guess theres something in that documents folder that the app needs. Once i switched to just deleting that file i created the error went away.